# Collection Empty on Findall in JPARepository

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 JPA entities.

*FormattedText.java*

```
@Entity
public class FormattedText extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "refFormattedText",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<FormattedText_Product> formattedText_products = new HashSet<FormattedText_Product>(0);
}
```

*FormattedText_Product .java*

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"formattedTextType","refProduct"}))
public class FormattedText_Product extends BaseEntity{

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "refFormattedText")
    private FormattedText refFormattedText;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "refProduct")
    private Product refProduct;

    @Column(name="formattedTextType")
    private FormattedTextType formattedTextType;
}
```

*Product .java*

```
@Entity
public class Product extends BaseEntity{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "refProduct",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<FormattedText_Product> formattedText_products = new HashSet<FormattedText_Product>(0);

}
```

So, FormattedText_Product is a join table.

I have a JPA Repository:

```
public interface FormattedTextRepository extends GenericJpaRepository<FormattedText, Integer>{

}
```

When I do:

```
FormattedTextRepository formattedTextRepository;
formattedTextRepository.findAll();
```

I got all the **FormattedText** with the **formattedText_products** collection not empty.

But when I do:

```
FormattedTextRepository formattedTextRepository;
List<FormattedText> list = formattedTextRepository.findAll();
list.getFormattedText_products().get(0).getRefProduct().getFormattedText_products().size();
```

The size is 0.
But if I do:

```
FormattedTextRepository formattedTextRepository;
List<FormattedText> list = formattedTextRepository.findAll();
FormattedText ft = list.getFormattedText_products().get(0);

entityManager.refresh(ft);

ft.getRefProduct().getFormattedText_products().size();
```

I got the correct size of the collection. It containing the formattedText_products object of the product.

Is it possible to do something to have the collection of **Product** from **FormattedText_Product** populated on the findAll() method?

Tahnks in advance

Julien

Comment: I'm just curious why you even created the 'join table' entity - can't you just work with an n:m relationship?

Comment: I can't remember the exact reason, but I believe it is best/required if you need to cascade some operations (delete, etc).

Comment: @home We used the Join table entity because in our real case we have an specific column in the join table. I update the code.